# What actually a "result object" of a prvalue expression is?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, temporary-objects, result-object

The standard states in [[basic.lval]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lval#5) the following:

> [..] The result object of a prvalue is the object initialized by the
> prvalue [..]

which is synchronized with the definition of a prvalue stated in [[basic.lval]/(1.2)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lval#1.2):

> A prvalue is an expression whose evaluation initializes an **object** [..]

So as far as I understand, the evaluation of a prvalue expression initializes an object called "result object", and this "result object" *is* the object that's initialized by this prvalue. For example:

```
struct S {};

int main(void){
    S s = S();
}
```

here `S()` is a prvalue expression, and I think that `s` is its result object (may be incorrect, and that's what I am asking for) because, per the first quote, `s` is the object initialized by the prvalue `S()`. Now, if `s` actually is the result object, where does the result object here:

```
struct X {};

int main(void){
     X();
}
```

here `X()` prvalue has no result object because it isn't initialized by any objects; Right?

---

I fell into this confusion when I saw the following code in [Clang AST](https://godbolt.org/z/o4GEqb5PY):
(I'm sorry for trying to open an unrelated question, but I will summarize AFAIC)

```
struct Y {};

int main() { 
    Y y = Y(); 
}
```

The following is the AST produced from the above code: (...omitted...)

```
....
...
`-FunctionDecl <line:5:1, line:7:1> line:5:5 main 'int ()'
  `-CompoundStmt <col:12, line:7:1>
    `-DeclStmt <line:6:5, col:14>
      `-VarDecl <col:5, col:13> col:7 y 'Y':'Y' cinit
        `-CXXTemporaryObjectExpr <col:11, col:13> 'Y':'Y' 'void () noexcept' zeroing
```

The last line shows clearly there's an un-materialized temporary get created. When I tried to understand why this temporary object was created, correctly or incorrectly, I checked this text in the standard: ([[class.temporary]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.temporary#3))

> **When an object of class type X is** passed to or **returned from a function**, if X has at least one eligible copy or move constructor ([special]), each such constructor is trivial, and the destructor of X is either trivial or deleted, **implementations are permitted to create a temporary object to hold** the function parameter or **result object**.
>
> [..]

I'm not sure that I have spotted the correct paragraph. But if so, the above paragraph says that the created temporary object holds the "result object", and I see that the result object here is `y`; right? I have confusion here: how the result object is `y` meanwhile `y` is not yet initialized? Does the result object here is the object produced from the constructor call? or something else?

I apologize if there are any conflicts in my questions or if the questions are based on misunderstanding.

Comment: `X()` actually *does* create an object – a temporary one that is destroyed again immediately after creation. You'll notice if you implement a custom class providing some output in constructor and destructor. This object, albeit not assigned anywhere, is the result object…

Comment: @Aconcagua - The definition of the result object *is the object initialized by the prvalue* - so what is the object that's initialized by prvalue `X()`? Is this object a temporary object?

Comment: Exactly that (*'a temporary one that[...]'*).

Comment: @Aconcagua That's fine. Accordingly, do you agree that the result object of `Y()` is also a temporary object *not* `y`?

Comment: When you write `X()`, then a *temporary materialization conversion* happens. I.e., a place for a temporary object is allocated out of thin air, which is then initialized by the prvalue expression `X()`. Of course, that temporary object is then destructed right away.

Comment: @mada To be honest in this specific case I'm not fully sure; coming to the easier case first: If you have created the `Y` object already before, as in `Y y; y = Y();` then there is a temporary object created which is passed on to the copy (or move) assignment operator (for `y`). In this case this temporary is the result object. `Y y = Y();` – if I recall correctly this expression leads to direct initialisation of `y` without any intermediate temporary (no copy constructor called!) – if indeed so, then `y` is the result object as well, but won't put my hand in fire for…

Comment: AFAIK, the paragraph that you cite near the end of the post gives the compiler a license to create more temporary objects than the language would otherwise require. It does so only for "trivial" classes, so that the extra copies cannot be detected with language features. It enables compilers to pass values of class type in registers.

Comment: OK, both GCC and clang seem to [prove me right](https://godbolt.org/z/Gjcz5hjjj) – but the output yielded by both might actually be a result of (mandatory) *copy elision* as well while in terms of the standard `Y()` still constructs a temporary result object. @molbdnilo (as knowing you being firmer on the standard than me…) could you possibly shed some light on (it's the `Y y = Y()` case only)?

Comment: _here `X()` prvalue has no result object because it isn't initialized by any objects; Right?_ No. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.context#2.sentence-6 https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.rval#1.sentence-2

Comment: @molbdnilo _Evaluating that expression creates an object_ Nope

Comment: @j6t _It does so only for "trivial" classes, so that the extra copies cannot be detected with language features_ WDYM by «language features»? Extra copying can be observed.

Comment: @Aconcagua _in terms of the standard `Y()` still constructs a temporary result object_ Nope

Comment: Confirmed by @LanguageLawyer: `Y y = Y()` indeed omits the temporary right away, thus `y` is directly initialised, so in this case `y` is the result object.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Saying "Nope" and referring to two unrelated sections of the standard is not a great argument.

Comment: _referring to two unrelated sections of the standard is not a great argument_ Why are you referring to https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.temporary#3, then?

Comment: _Saying "Nope" and referring to_ These are different comments

Comment: @LanguageLawyer - It seems to me that you're referring to irrelevant standard wording ([conv.rval]): Who tells you that the created temporary duto `Y()` is materialized?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer This means that not all temporaries created by an implementation is materialized (see [class.temporary]/1)

Comment: @Aconcagua - Copy elision is also applied in my `Y` example. I see here that the result object is the object produced from the constructor call `Y()` (temporary?). Then this result object had to copied to `y` by a call to copy constructor. But because copy elision is mandated in this example, this copy is elided and, instead, `y` is direct-initialized from the result object.

Comment: @j6t - *When you write X(), then a temporary materialization conversion happens.* If you're trusting clang, clang has a class called [MaterializeTemporaryExpr](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1MaterializeTemporaryExpr.html) that's invoked when a temporary is materialized.  That's not the case in my Y-example. The standard tells you that a temporary is materialized when binding reference to prvalue. Check [this](https://godbolt.org/z/hqhcvx4zv) and you will find that the temporary is materialized and that has clearly appeared in clang AST.

Comment: If you mean the `Y()` that is part of `Y y = Y();`, then you are correct that no temporary materialization happens. I should have been more specific: when you write `X();` as in your other example (i.e., that  is the whole statement), then a temporary materialization conversion happens, because this is a [discarded value expression](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.context#2).

Comment: _Who tells you that the created temporary duto `Y()` is materialized?_ I was citing your question about `X();`. See italicized text in that comment? And before referring to [conv.rval], I've linked https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.context#2.sentence-6

Answer (score 0):

> and I think that s is its result object

Yes, correct. In particular there is no temporary object that could be the result object instead (since C++17).

> here X() prvalue has no result object because it isn't initialized by any objects; Right?

The expression `X()` in the expression statement `X();` is a *discarded-value expression* per [[stmt.expr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/stmt.stmt#stmt.expr-1.sentence-2).

After potential conversions which are not relevant here, a prvalue expression that is a discarded-value expression has the temporary materialization conversion applied per [[expr.context]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.context#2.sentence-6).

The effect of temporary materialization conversion is to introduce a temporary object that is initialized from the prvalue per [[conv.rval]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.rval).

This temporary object is therefore the result object of the prvalue.

> I fell into this confusion when I saw the following code in Clang AST

`CXXTemporaryObjectExpr` probably (I am guessing here) only indicates an expression of the form `T(E)` where `T` is a non-reference type and `E` is either an empty expression list or a list of two or more expressions and isn't intended to state anything about applied temporary materialization conversions.

Before C++17, this syntax generally caused the creation of a temporary object (before optional copy elision), which is why the name makes sense. Since C++17 there are many cases where this expression syntax will *not* cause the creation of a temporary object as you demonstrate. They probably simply didn't change the Clang-internal naming.

Your quote from the standard is not relevant here since there is no function that takes or returns a `S`.

---

Note that the above applies to C++17 and later only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And I am glad to see you agree with me that the last wording is somehow irrelevant as I thought and clarified in the question. But clang manual says that [CXXTemporaryObjectExpr](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CXXTemporaryObjectExpr.html) *Represents a C++ functional cast expression that **builds a temporary object*** - Doesn't that mean there's a temporary created as a result of this cast expression?

Comment: @mada I guess the documentation is just imprecise or wasn't correctly updated for C++17.

Comment: @mada The example they give in the documentation also doesn't necessarily imply construction of a temporary depending on the use at the call site. (Although in that case [class.temporary]/3 does apply and depending on the ABI there may be a temporary introduced regardless of the use at the call site.)

Comment: Accordingly, (since c++17) you see that there are no temporaries necessarily created in case `Y y = Y()`?

Comment: @mada It is _guaranteed_ that there is no temporary created in that statement (since C++17).